# Выборка из таблиц со связью Many To Many

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

в БД PostgreSQL есть таблица Provider со строками id и name. Также есть таблица Currencies с полями id и currency, и Countries с полями id и country. Между Provider и Currencies, и Provider и Countries связь Many to Many, соответственно есть 2 таблицы ссылок provcurr и provcountries. Каждому провайдеру может соответствовать произвольное количество countries и currencies.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы прочитать из таблицы провайдеров с заданной страной и вернуть в виде списка.

Выглядит это на данный момент как-то так:

```
private static String SELECT_BY_COUNTRY = "SELECT * " +
        "                                           FROM provider " +
        "                                           INNER JOIN provcurr" +
        "                                           ON provider.id = provcurr.idprov" +
        "                                           INNER JOIN provider_curr " +
        "                                           ON provider_curr.id = idcurr" +
        "                                           INNER JOIN provcountry" +
        "                                           ON provider.id = provcountry.idprov" +
        "                                           INNER JOIN provider_country" +
        "                                           ON provider_country.id = idcountry" +
        "                                           WHERE country = ?";


public ArrayList<Provider> select(Country country) {
    ArrayList<Provider> result = null;
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_BY_COUNTRY);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, country.toString());
        ResultSet provider = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        result = createProviderList(provider);

        System.out.println(result);

        System.out.println("All providers was selected from database");
        System.out.println("Generating provider's list");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to select providers \n" + e.toString());
    } finally {
        return result;
    }
}

private ArrayList<Provider> createProviderList(ResultSet provider) throws SQLException {
    Map<String, Provider> providers = new HashMap<>();
    while (provider.next()) {
        String providerName = provider.getString("name");
        if (!providers.containsKey(providerName)) {
            providers.put(providerName, new Provider(providerName, new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>()));
        }
        if (!providers.get(providerName).containsCurrencsy(provider.getString("currency"))) {
            providers.get(providerName).addCurrency(provider.getString("currency"));
        }
        if (!providers.get(providerName).containsCountry(provider.getString("country"))) {
            providers.get(providerName).addCountry(provider.getString("country"));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List was generated");
    return new ArrayList<Provider>(providers.values());
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при таком запросе я получаю в результате только заданную страну. При этом провайдеру может соответствовать далеко не только эта страна.

Собственно вопрос - как одним запросом получить провайдеров, которым соответствует заданная страна со списком всех остальных стран и валют?

Схема таблиц (стрелка от provcurr к provider в другую сторону):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подклеить таблицу в которой содержится поле country (в запросе этого не понятно, а структуру таблиц вы в вопросе почему то не привели) в запрос еще раз, на этот раз только с условиями  объединения, без фильтрации по стране. Разумеется использовать алиасы, что бы одну таблицу дважды спокойно использовать

Comment: Подцепил схему таблиц. Если честно, не до конца понял как это сделать, чтобы при этом работала фильтрация.

Comment: Интересно что вы хотите получить. Скажем есть один провайдер у которого две страны UK и RU и три валюты RUR, USD и EUR. Сколько строк вы ожидаете получить на выходе и как они должны выглядеть. Ведь если просто переклеить так, как вы сейчас делаете получится 6 строк. три UK со всеми валютами и три RU со всеми валютами

Comment: А вообще раз уж все равно таблицы доклеивать возможно проще было бы фильтр переписать на `where provider.id IN(select idprov from provcountry p, provider_coutry c where c.country=? and p.idcountry=c.id)`

Comment: В конечном варианте это должен быть экземпляр класса Provider, у которого есть два листа: List<Currency> currencies и List<Country> countries. Все валюты и страны, соответствующие этому провайдеру, должны автоматом сложиться в эти листы без дубликатов. В случае с Вашим примером да, получится 6 строк, которые в итоге должны разложиться в один экземпляр класса Provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда запрос становится сложным и запутанным, значит проблемы со схемой базы данных. 
Если я правильно понял, то нужно вытащить всю информацию о провайдерах, которые привязаны к определенной стране. Если так то:

```
CREATE TABLE "provider"  ( 
"id"    int NOT NULL,
"name"  varchar(25) NOT NULL 
);
CREATE TABLE "provcountries"  ( 
    "idprov"    int NOT NULL,
    "idcountry" int NOT NULL 
    );
CREATE TABLE "provcurr"  ( 
    "idprov"    int NOT NULL,
    "idcurr"    int NOT NULL 
    );
CREATE TABLE "provider_curr"  ( 
    "id"        int NOT NULL,
    "currency"  varchar(25) NOT NULL 
    );
CREATE TABLE "provider_сountry"  ( 
    "id"        int NULL,
    "country"   varchar(25) NULL 
    );


INSERT INTO provider VALUES (1, 'provider1');
INSERT INTO provider VALUES (2, 'provider2');
INSERT INTO provider VALUES (3, 'provider3');

INSERT INTO provider_curr VALUES (1, 'currency1');
INSERT INTO provider_curr VALUES (2, 'currency2');
INSERT INTO provider_curr VALUES (3, 'currency3');

INSERT INTO provider_сountry VALUES (1, 'country1');
INSERT INTO provider_сountry VALUES (2, 'country2');
INSERT INTO provider_сountry VALUES (3, 'country3');

INSERT INTO provcountries VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO provcountries VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO provcountries VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO provcountries VALUES (3, 1);

INSERT INTO provcurr VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO provcurr VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO provcurr VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO provcurr VALUES (3, 2);

SELECT
    p.id            AS provider_id,
    p.name          AS provider_name,
    cur.idcurr      AS currency_id,
    cur.currency    AS currency_name,
    co.idcountry    AS country_id,
    co.country      AS country_name
FROM
    ( SELECT id, name FROM provider WHERE id IN (SELECT idprov FROM provcountries WHERE idcountry = 1) ) AS p
    LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT idprov, idcountry, country FROM provcountries pco JOIN provider_сountry co ON (co.id = pco.idcountry)) AS co
    ON (p.id = co.idprov)
    LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT idprov, idcurr, currency FROM  provcurr pcr JOIN provider_curr cr ON (cr.id = pcr.idcurr) ) AS cur
    ON (p.id = cur.idprov)
```

Результат:

```
provider_id;provider_name;currency_id;currency_name;country_id;country_name
1;provider1;1;currency1;2;country2
1;provider1;2;currency2;2;country2
1;provider1;1;currency1;1;country1
1;provider1;2;currency2;1;country1
3;provider3;2;currency2;1;country1
```

Comment: Что бы упростить преобразование в сущности, можно делать несколько запросов, например: 1. Получить всех провайдеров со странами (+если необходимо добавить фильтрацию) 2. Получит всех провайдеров с валютами 3. Объединить списки